# A bean problem from Trader Joe's disguised as a marble problem

Tags: probability

So Trader Joe's has a product called 17-Bean Soup.
For the purposes of this problem, you may assume a large number of beans with an equal number of each type of bean. If an exact number of each bean is required, you may use 100,000. We buy in bulk.
What is the probability of taking 17 beans from the bin and having one and exactly one of each type of bean? The beans are not replaced; I grab 17 beans and that's it.
I think the answer is easier to arrive at than I am making it, but I can't quite get there.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you heard of the hypergeometric distribution ?

Comment: I have not heard of it; I have a *very* basic math background but also an interest in this sort of probability problem.

Comment: Have you done probability problems of drawing without replacement ?

Answer (score 3):

The probability of pulling any bean with the first go is $\frac{17}{17}$. The probability for the second bean to be different is $\frac{16}{17}$, for the third go to be again a different bean is $\frac{15}{17}$, and so on.

So your final probability is $\frac{17!}{17^{17}}$.

Note that this method tends the number of beans to infinity, otherwise it is an approximation.

Comment: Nice explanation. (+1)

Comment: @CarstenS; I assumed that 'a large number of beans' means I can tend $N\to\infty$

Comment: @CarstenS; edited.

Answer (score 2):

Because you're encouraged to think in terms of a huge
population, it seems OK to ignore the difference between sampling with and without replacement for a draw of 17 beans.

**Two.** Try it for two hinds of beans. Equivalent to getting
one H and and one T on two tosses of a fair coin: $2!(1/2)^2 = 1/2.$

**Six.** How about six kinds? What's the probability of seeing
all six faces in 6 rolls of a fair die?

Simulate it for a million 6-roll experiments. With a
million iterations you should get two or three place
accuracy, with good luck maybe more: $6!(1/6)^6 = 0.0154321.$

```
set.seed(2021)
nr = replicate(10^6, length(unique(sample(1:6, 6, rep=T))))
mean(nr==6)
[1] 0.015415      # aprx prob of seeing all 6 faces
2*sd(nr==6)/1000
[1] 0.0002463931  # aprx 95% margin of simulation err

factorial(6)*(1/6)^6
[1] 0.0154321     # exact
```

**Seventeen.** See a pattern? Now what about $17!(1/17)^{17} = 0.000\,000\,43?$ Don't expect to see all 17 kinds of beans
in every cup of this soup.

```
factorial(17)*(1/17)^17
[1] 4.299687e-07
```

But in every draw of 17, you have a pretty good chance
(87%) of getting at least ten different kinds of beans.

```
set.seed(2021)
nr = replicate(10^6, length(unique(sample(1:17, 17, rep=T))))
mean(nr >= 10)
[1] 0.871177
2*sd(nr >= 10)/1000
[1] 0.0006700082
```

And if your can of soup has 100 beans, you're almost
sure to see all 17 kinds, provided all kinds are equally likely.

```
set.seed(1234)
nr = replicate(10^6, length(unique(sample(1:17, 100, rep=T))))
mean(nr >= 17)
[1] 0.960872
2*sd(nr >= 17)/1000
[1] 0.0003877991
```